# Send multiple requests in sequence in Angular 5 resolver

Tags: angular5

I have multiple requests in my angular 5 app's resolver function. I want one requests to be sent and then I want the others to be sent only after the first one has been responded.

I have had a look at `forkJoin` in `rxJS`, but somehow not able to achieve the sequential thing?

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I ended up using flatMap callback, basically from the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html), it allows us to perform sequential tasks and return observable in the end.

You can try something like in the `resolve` function of the resolver,

```
return request1().flatMap( (response: any) => {
    return forkJoin( [ request2(), request3() ];
} );
```

Where request1 is the function that you want to be performed before request2 and request3 are executed. It goes without saying that, all the requests must be returning Observables.